# Cox regression - unknowns within covariates

Tags: survival, cox-model

I have run a model for duration in treatment. Records have either exited treatment or are still in treatment. If exited, the number of days is known. If still in treatment, the number of days in treatment so far was calcualted on a particular date.

My query relates to missing information in the covariates. Every case has a response for every variable. "Not known"  was recorded in a number of scenarios (when the respondent refused to answer the question, when they didn't know the answer, when the data collector missed the question, etc). I should mention that this is a secondary data analysis, so I have no way of distingishing between the different kinds of Not knowns. From a software perspective it appears as though I have no missing data because every variable has something recorded.

There is a lot of information online about missing data for the outcome but not so much easy to read information about missing information within covariates.  I looking for advice on how I should address the problem in my dataset.

Answer (score 0):

The literature on missing data is pretty clear. If a lab tech drops and shatters a vial of biospecimen on the way to the centrifuge, you can use complex models to impute the values.

In surveys and self-report, levels of "don't know" or "not applicable" are the most informative levels of response available. To put it bluntly: refused/don't know/not applicable is very much non-missing and highly informative. As you design and analyze your response, propose hazard ratios for the outcome comparing NA/DK/NR levels to other "given" levels, and be prepared to interpret their findings.

Be aware of bad survey design. For instance, if an instrument is sent to men and women, and asks, "Are you pregnant or nursing?" then who might answer "not applicable"? men? non-fecund women (underage girls, post-menopausal women, and/or women with hysterectomy)? In each of those cases, the "N/A" vs. "no" response compares the average hazard for each of those types of individual against fecund women who are not pregnant or nursing. It is useful to estimate effects and describe the possible limitations of the survey instrument design, and suggest modifications.

The type of model is inconsequential. I would recommend a similar approach for Cox, logistic, and linear regression alike.

Comment: Thank you AdamO, this is really helpful and exactly what I have done in my model. Could you suggest some references for doing this over a missing values analysis? If you could point me in the right direction it would be really useful. Thank you!

Comment: @Statshelpneeded I have a chip on my shoulder on "cite everything" logic. You can *cite* research that is wrong, or more often not applicable. It is no replacement for clearly explaining ideas. I wouldn't even bother describing. Present the results in a way that makes the most sense, they justify themselves. If a reviewer is confused, gently educate them.

Comment: I think in this particular situation an appropriate citation will make the difference between getting over the hurdle or not.

Comment: @Statshelpneeded I think you will not know that until you submit your paper. The purpose of this site is to get an expert's opinion, you did that and got mine. Some stuff is too trivial or informed by preponderance of practice to involve a citation. You don't, for instance, cite the algorithm used to calculate the p-values from a normal distribution.